# How to get Current Working Directory of PowerBI in Python?

Tags: python, powerbi

I need to import a file into PowerBI via Python.  I need some way to make the file paths in the Python code be dynamic.  Is there a way to reference the current working directory of the power bi file in python code?  os.getcwd() isn't working in the python script editor of PowerBi.

Answer (score 2):

Found a round about solution for a semi-dynamic way to change file directory:

1) create a parameter in powerbi that has the file path to but not including the file
    eg: C:\Users\User\Documents\Folder\

2) Need to run your initial import job with static file references in your python code
    eg: C:\Users\User\Documents\Folder\file.xlsx

3) Once your python created table is in, go into the query editor > Advanced Editor

4) Now for every reference of the full file path we will break the python code and insert the PowerBI parameter object using **" & Parameter & "**
    eg: ...df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Folder\file.xlsx')...
    becomes: ...df = pd.read_excel(r'" & Parameter & "file.xlsx')...

This allows the end_user to be able to easily change the directory by just modifying the parameter, without having to touch any of the python code.